# Azure SQL bulk insert from blob storage failure: Referenced external data source "MyAzureBlobStorage" not found

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, bulkinsert

I keep getting this error (**Referenced external data source "MyAzureBlobStorage" not found.**) when loading csv from blob to Azure SQL. I am following [this](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/features/sql-bulk-load/load-from-azure-blob-storage/LoadFromAzureBlobStorage.sql) example and I set my blob to be public but the following just does not work:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
          LOCATION = 'https://test.blob.core.windows.net/test'
);
BULK INSERT SubscriberQueue
FROM 'inputs.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage', FORMAT='CSV');
```

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: Could you please tell me which auth method  you use to connect Azure Blob storage?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bulk insert  from Azure blob, please refer to following script

1. my csv file

```
1,Peter,Jackson,pjackson@hotmail.com
2,Jason,Smith,jsmith@gmail.com
3,Joe,Raasi,jraasi@hotmail.com
```

2. script

```
create table listcustomer
(id int, 
firstname varchar(60),
lastname varchar(60), 
email varchar(60))
Go


CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
          LOCATION = 'https://****.blob.core.windows.net/test'
);
Go

BULK INSERT listcustomer
FROM 'mycustomers.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage', FORMAT='CSV');
Go

select * from listcustomer;
```

[image]