# Referencing ABS location for stored procedure Using Azure Data Factory

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

My ADF pipeline processes through many imput files and lands them on an ABS container.
A 3rd party stored proc has two params: filename and datasourcelocation and does a bulk insert into an Azure SQL DB.

For the Data Source Location I pass:   landing/Vendor
For the Data File /Company_05_17_22_05_54.csv

The full ABS location is for a single file is:   https://...use2dev01.blob.core.windows.net/landing/Vendor/Company_05_17_22_05_54.csv

The error message says

Execution fail against sql server. Sql error number: 12703. Error Message: Referenced external data source "landing/vendor" not found.

How should I be passing the ABS location to the proc?

Answer (score 0):

> The error message says
>
> Execution fail against sql server. Sql error number: 12703. Error Message: Referenced external data source "landing/vendor" not found.

For this error you can create a new data source (eg myazureblobstorage1 and provided that name in the second BULK command)

- Try to Check the **TLS version** of the storage account. sometimes TLS settings may cause this error
- Try to create the external data source ,wait for mins before running the BULK Insert
- Check the **CSV file** is formatted properly, it may cause other issues
- Take a note of additional parameters in the BULK Insert command
- Make sure Table column names must **match** with that of CSV file

If you want to bulk insert from Azure blob, please refer to following script of [so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64692863/azure-sql-bulk-insert-from-blob-storage-failure-referenced-external-data-source)

Please check if the data source exists , You can verify the name of the data source by querying `sys.external_data_sources` and referring this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver15)

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Bulk insert from Azure blob storage to Azure SQL database](https://sqlserverguides.com/bulk-loading-data-to-azure-sql/)

[SQL Server BULK INSERT does not work with Azure Blob Storage emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/242043/sql-server-bulk-insert-does-not-work-with-azure-bl.html)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal